# onclick on canvas android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I wanted touch event on every bitmap drawn using canvas

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, points.get(i).x, points.get(i).y, null);
```

any help is appreciated

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- implement onTouchListener.
- inside constructor > setOnTouchListener(this)
- you have coordinates of all bitmaps, so inside onTouchListener get X,Y coordinates and compare with bitmap coordinates and take action accordingly.

Comment: i have drawn a grid using array in the Snake Sample works in android sdk,

so in that sample you can find tile view class please help me in the when the tiles are poped up i want to click on any one of them how can i change the bitmap in onClick

Comment: please [check](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Snake/src/com/example/android/snake/TileView.html) here in ondraw bitmap is drawn fro each and every bitmap i want to set onclick event, bitmap drawn on a grid using array 
any help is appreciated
thanks